# Error during program execution in function that returns another function

Tags: c++, lambda

I try to call the 'testfun' function inside 'test' function using 'std::function', reducing variables number by 1 and performing intermediate calculations.

The 'A' class (vector) contains a 1D array of double.

During execution the program terminates at the specified point and 'functional' file is opened on 'const auto _Impl = _Getimpl();' line. How to solve the problem?

```
#include <functional>

class A
{
public:
    double* d;
    unsigned s;

    A(unsigned size)
    {
        s = size;
        d = new double[s];
    }
};

double testfun(A* param, A* x)
{
    return param->d[0] + param->d[1] * x->d[0];
}

std::function<double(A*)> anon(std::function<double(A*, A*)> f, A& x, A& y)
{
    std::function<double(A*)> result = [&](A * param_)
    {
        // Program fails somewhere at that point

        double sum = 0.0;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < x.s; i++)
            sum += f(param_, &x) - y.d[i];

        return sum;
    };

    return result;
}

double test(std::function<double(A*, A*)> f)
{
    A x(1); A y(1);
    x.d[0] = 0.0;
    y.d[0] = 2.0;

    A* param = new A(2);
    param->d[0] = 2.0; param->d[1] = 6.0;

    std::function<double(A*)> func = anon(f, x, y);

    return func(param);
}

void main()
{
    double t = test(testfun);
}
```

Comment: `main`'s return type is required to be `int`.

Comment: "program terminates at the specified point": specified how?

Comment: I added the comment with the point where program fails

Comment: changing 'void' to 'int' does not seem to be a solution =)

Comment: It is undefined behaviour `anon` takes `f` by reference, but `f` is local you have dangling reference in `result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that is the only problem but is a problem.

In the following function

```
std::function<double(A*)> anon(std::function<double(A*, A*)> f, A& x, A& y)
{
    std::function<double(A*)> result = [&](A * param_)
    {
        // Program fails somewhere at that point

        double sum = 0.0;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < x.s; i++)
            sum += f(param_, &x) - y.d[i];

        return sum;
    };

    return result;
}
```

the returned lambda receive `f` by reference bit `anon()` receive `f` by copy.

So when you call the returned lambda **outside** `anon()`, it contains a dangling reference to `f`.

Suggestion: try passing `f`, to the lambda, by copy.

```
// ....................................V  f by copy
std::function<double(A*)> result = [&, f](A * param_)
 { /* lambda content */ }
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a problem. How to code it correctly? I tried to create a copy of 'f' like ```std::function<double(A*, A*)> f1 = f;``` but this results in the same error

Comment: @Perotto - as suggested at the end of the answer, try passing `f`, to the lambda, by copy: `std::function<double(A*)> result = [&, f](A * param_)`